# Adding custom membership to forms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a site that uses the asp.net membership tables (ASP 3.5 site).  I am going to use an excel sheet to periodically add users to the membership tables and I want to upload all the excel information via a form.  I used a little form app to process the excel sheet and am now ready to add the information to the membership tables.

Is there a way to invoke the membership class for the membership tables and add a user manually from the from as the excel sheet is processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Membership.CreateUser()

Here's the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.createuser.aspx)